# How to create a multiple view based app without using the navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am relatively new to programming for the iphone OS, but know the basics and some other things. What I am wondering is how would I program an app that acts like there is a navigation controller, just without the navigation controller bar that comes with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try a **UITabBarController** : [`UITabBarController Class Reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the navigationBar that comes with the controller and maintain all the functionality that the navigationController provides. Pass the following method to the navigationController to hide/show the bar.

```
- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to have a main view that you swap out subviews from, using an animation as you add or remove views...

But using a navigation controller with the navigation bar hidden as Daniel noted is much simpler.